# Error encountered while trying to upload Quercus to hosting server

Tags: java, php, jsp, tomcat, quercus

I am new to Quercus, I am trying to run PHP on my TOMCAT HOST.

Everything works fine on my local tomcat server, however, after I uploaded it to my hosting server(EATJ) I have the following Errors:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.caucho.vfs.FilePath
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServletImpl.init(QuercusServletImpl.java:87)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet.initImpl(QuercusServlet.java:531)
at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet.init(QuercusServlet.java:441)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:120)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And also:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.PropertyPermission user.dir read)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:323)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:546)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPropertyAccess(SecurityManager.java:1285)
    at java.lang.System.getProperty(System.java:652)
    at com.caucho.vfs.Path.getUserDir(Path.java:1593)
    at com.caucho.vfs.FilePath.getPwd(FilePath.java:115)
    at com.caucho.vfs.FilePath.initialPath(FilePath.java:94)
    at com.caucho.vfs.FilePath.<init>(FilePath.java:75)
    at com.caucho.vfs.Path.<clinit>(Path.java:1665)
    at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServletImpl.init(QuercusServletImpl.java:87)
    at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet.initImpl(QuercusServlet.java:531)
    at com.caucho.quercus.servlet.QuercusServlet.init(QuercusServlet.java:441)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:271)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Was wondering if anyone has done this before and can help me with it.